# Create-react-app not loading JavaScript on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs

I'm attempting to get my web app that has been bootstrapped with `create-react-app` to load on iOS browsers (both Chrome and Safari). To simplify things, I replaced the `ReactDOM.render` call that would usually start my app with the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

// ReactDOM.render(
//   <App />,
//   document.getElementById('root')
// );

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Huzzah</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

However it doesn't seem to get called. I have the new Chrome mobile console open and logging (by opening a tab and going to `chrome://inspect` and nothing is being logged. The CSS seems to be getting applied though, as I changed the background to pink as another test.

I'm following the standard `create-react-app` commands and build directory of `yarn build`, and `/build`, and deploying to Netlify.

TL;DR my app isn't loading on iOS, and as a result a blank page is being shown.

**Does anyone know how to fix this and/or debug it further?** (I don't have access to a Mac computer, so my options for debug tools are limited).

---

Update: I've determined something in my `App.js` file is the culprit. I'm recreating it from scratch until I hit a point where it stops working to find what is causing the blank page. Will post the answer if I solve it.

Comment: did you solve it? i'm having a similar issue with iOs mobile (mac works just fine)...

Comment: can you update it when if you solved it please?